# Unable to center table in CSS... (Internet explorer)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Centering and alignments works just fine on IE and Firefox. I haven't done HTML/CSS for quite some time, so I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong. I have already searched around and no table centering has worked for me.

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6n7ufL9/**

---

```css
    /* different things I tried to get to work */
    #table {
      display: table;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      table-layout: auto;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #ececec;
    }
    #navborderline {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 5px;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: black;
    }
    #navborder ul {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #navborder ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%;
    }
    #navborder a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #navborder a:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    }
    #navborder {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #table {
      width: 60%;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 5px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #table td,
    tr {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Travis' Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />
  <!--[if IE]>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
            <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="navborder">
    <ul id="ie">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Assignments</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Random</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="mainbody">
    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Ello</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>hello v2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>hello v2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="mainfooter"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On one line you say it works in IE and Firefox, then you say it doesn't work in IE. Which is it?

Comment: In your fiddle, you link to (CSS) resources that aren't available, that pretty much renders that fiddle useless. (Also, `HTML` and `HEAD` tags aren't necessary (allowed) in jsfiddle.)

Comment: never mind, i posted an answer but i think i understood your question wrong...i will delete the answer. sorry